# Using Hindi Numbers

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to use Hindi numbers instead of Arabic numbers without changing the English Interface. I tried to change it by changing the Regional formats, but with no success. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does your font support Hindi numbers?